# Mostrando um ícone para diretório e outro para demais arquivos

Tags: php, arquivo

Preciso ler um diretório e alterar seus ícones. Caso seja um diretório, aplica um ícone, caso seja um arquivo .txt aplique outro ícone.

Segue o código que fiz:

```
<?php

$dir = 'ftp/';
$pasta = opendir($dir);

while ($arquivo = readdir($pasta)){
    // Caso o arquivo tenho '.' identificaria como .txt
    if ($arquivo = '.' ){
        echo "<img src='../img/pasta.ico'>";
    } else {           
        echo "<img src='../img/archive.ico'>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Esqueci de add o '}' para fechar o while.

Comment: Tem erros de programação, um deles seria `$arquivo =` ta faltando mais um igual, porque, comparação são dois ou três: `$arquivo ==` ou `$arquivo ===` (com três além de comparar o valor compara o tipo)

Comment: Não funcionou a minha versão?

Comment: Funcionou Jorge B. Agradeço. Mas a resposta do Júnior, foi mais satisfatória.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu fiz uma versão do seu código, só que usando a classe **DirectoryIterator**, o código abaixo checa o tipo e é só continuar o switch  para obter o resultado que deseja.

```
foreach ( new DirectoryIterator('css') as $file ) {
if ( !$file->isDot() ) {
    if ( $file->isDir() ) {
        echo $file->getBaseName();
    } else {
        switch ( $file->getExtension() ) {
            case 'txt':
                echo '<img src="txt.png">' . $file->getBaseName();
            break;

            case 'css':
                echo '<img src="css.png">' . $file->getBaseName();
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Alguma dúvida pergunte nos comentários.

Answer (score 3):

Pode verificar assim se é diretorio ou não:

```
if (is_dir($dir)){

}
```